# Unresponsive Eclipse preferences (And other dialogs) on Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse

I'm using a Linux distribution called **Manjaro**, it's based on a distribution called **Arch**.

The problem I'm facing is that sometimes, Eclipse becomes somehow unresponsive. The case I'm currently facing is that when I open the preferences dialog, choosing a preference section doesn't usually show the relative controls.

Check the attached image for an example, I'm selecting **Colors and Fonts** after viewing **Archetypes**. The **Archetypes** controls are still showing while the **Colors and Fonts** preference section is selected !

This rarely work fine and instantly, some other times it takes minutes for the correct controls to show up, or doesn't show up at all !

Another symptom is selecting a maven archetype while creating a maven project\module. No archetypes would show up. Even after I manually configured a remote archetype catalog, no archetype would show up, even if I type in part of the archetype name.

I used both **Oracle JDK** and **Oracle JDK**, none made a difference !

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be hitting a GTK3 bug.

Try running in GTK2 mode to see if that resolves your problem.

### Running in GTK2 Mode

To run in GTK2 Mode, set environment variable `SWT_GTK3` to `0`, for example:

```
$ export SWT_GTK3=0
$ /path/to/eclipse -data /path/to/workspace
```

### File a Bug

If GTK2 resolves your issue, please file a bug on the [Eclipse Bug Tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform&component=UI) so it gets resolved.